# to remove parentheses while saving into csv file

Tags: python, list, tuples, parentheses

I want to remove `(` and `)` parentheses while saving to csv file.Below is my code where CC is list of tuples

```
CC = [(285, 573), (312, 572), (271, 572), (340, 568)]
with open( savecsv + oimg_name + ".csv", "a") as out_file:
                out_string = ""
                out_string += str(oimg_name)
                out_string +=  "\n" + "\n".join([str(i) for i in CC])
                out_string += "\n"
                out_file.write(out_string)
```

My output file contains bracket parenthese which I want to remove it

[image]

Comment: Why not use a [CSV module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer) or pandas? This lets you pass the tuples pretty much as-is, and it handles gluing it all together for you.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
out_string +=  "\n" + "\n".join([str(i) for i in CC])
```

with:

```
out_string +=  "\n" + "\n".join([f"{i[0]}, {i[1]}" for i in CC])
```

Your original solution doesn't work as you're applying **str** function to the *entire* *tuple*, not a *specific* *element* of the tuple. Using f-string is a more convenient and short way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

```
([str(i[0]) +" "+ str(i[1]) for i in CC])
```

You were taking a complete tuple instead add this line to further access the elements of
your tuple